# Wordpress permalinks not working after accidental URL change

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

So I accidentally changed the site URL of my website which broke it. It is supposed to be website.com/testsite, but I changed it to website.com instead.

Then I changed it back by editing the database in phpmyadmin. Things are kind of working again, except I noticed a lot of the pictures weren't pulling up. I inferred that the permalink structure was messed up, and when I checked in the permalink settings, the "plain" default permalink structure is website.com/?p=123. And it should be website.com/testsite/?p=123, yes? How do I fix this?

Comment: Go to settings >  Permalinks and update it twice

Comment: tried that, didn't work :(

Comment: Try to change permalinks to another structure, then save, then change it back to default and save again